# date picker disable hover on thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap date picker inside table with hover option. When going into date picker first two rows that are displaying month and day are overwritten by css from table and after hover side text is going white.

Here is working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- menu font awesome css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- momentum -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<style>
    .input-group {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
    .label_column {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .table > tbody > tr > td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .status {
        color: LawnGreen;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu  {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .datepicker table tr td {
        border-radius: 0%;
        border:dotted 1px black;
        background-color: SkyBlue;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        color: black;
    }
    .datepicker thead tr th:hover {
        color: black;
    }
</style>



<body>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-borderless table-dark">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="date_time_picker_csd" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date_time_picker_csd"
                               name="signing_date" required/>
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date_time_picker_csd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.input-group').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

How to change css or js to disable hover on first two rows in date picker?

Comment: you mean the number rows?

Comment: @MatanSanbira no, i mean month and days. after you hover on any day name the res of days text names color is going to by white according to table css setup.

Comment: This is because your CSS is interfering with the default CSS used by Bootstrap. Make your selectors more specific instead of globally selecting `td`/`tr` elements.

Comment: remove `table-dark` class, it is changing color of text to white.

Comment: @CodingOtaku table-dark must remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your stylesheet

```css
th.dow, th.next span{
  color:#000!important;
}
```

Comment: this working for days names but not for first row with displayed months names and arrows, can update you code?

Comment: if u getting the same issue even after adding the above css, thats because of any other css within your project..and that is not included in the snippet..

Comment: yep i know. I have found the solution thanks to You example: Insteed of `th.dow, th.next span` i use `.datepicker th`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
.table-dark.table-hover tbody tr:hover{
  color: #000 !important;
}
```